# Django: How to do reverse foreign key lookup of another class without an instance of this class?

Tags: python, django, static-methods, class-method, instance-method

I have the following two Django Classes `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`.

`MyClassB` has a foreign key reference to an instance of `MyClassA`.

```
from django.db import models

class MyClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    @classmethod
    def my_method_a(cls):
        # What do I put here to call MyClassB.my_method_b()??


class MyClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    my_class_a = models.ForeignKey(MyClassA, related_name="MyClassB_my_class_a")

    @staticmethod
    def my_method_b():
        return "Hello"
```

From within `MyClassA`'s class method `my_method_a`, I would like to call `MyClassB`'s static method `my_method_b`. How can I do it? If `my_method_a` was an instance method, I would simply do `self.MyClassB_my_class_a.model.my_method_b()`. But since I don't have an instance of `MyClassA`, I don't know how to do it.

Can I use `cls` instead of `self`?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm asking how to do this when you don't have the instance of MyClassA.

Comment: Apologies - retracting vote.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `staticmethod`, you don't need an instance.

You can call `MyClassB.my_method_b()` directly.

Comment: In `my_method_a()`, it doesn't know about `MyClassB`. They are in separate files. Can I use the `related_name` field to get from `my_method_a()` to `my_method_b()`?

Comment: So what?  Just import MyClassB.  If you don't want to do that for some reason, you can use [`get_model(app_label, model_name='MyClassB')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) instead.